# Does '到现在' imply a recent change?

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning

Chinese-to-English dictionaries seem to translate '到现在' as 'up to now' or 'until now'. In English this often implies a recent change in conditions rather than a continuation of conditions; however, in Chinese I don't seem to see this same implication.

Is this correct, that does '到现在' not imply a recent change? can it ever imply this by itself? If not, how would I convey the English logic (implied recent change) in Chinese?

Examples in English:

> We haven't heard from him until now.
>
> Up to now, we hadn't heard from him.

Both imply we just heard from him today or very recently.

Comment: how about giving some examples to facilitate the discussion?

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not imply a recent change.

「到現在」does literally translate to *until now*, but their usage is different, as you've already noted (a continuation of conditions).

- In English, *until now* means practically the same thing as *until recently*.
- In Chinese,「到現在」means something like *up to this very day* in English.「到現在我還在...」means *up to this very day, I'm still...*
- To say the equivalent of English *until now* (that is, implying a change in condition), you should say something similar to「到[目前](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%9B%AE%E5%89%8D)爲止...」.「爲止」is an explicit statement that stops the otherwise implied continuation.

Answer (score 1):

Better you have your examples and explain how English works.

In Chinese, '到现在' can implies ***either*** a recent change **or** a continuation of a condition depending on how you use it.

For example,

> 你怎么到现在才来 // a recent change - *he showed up now*.
>
> 你怎么到现在还不承认 // a continuation of a condition (不承认)